# zsh: Killed MacOS terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh

when I type python3 into the terminal on Visual Studio Code I get:

Python3
zsh: killed     python3

I also get the same thing in my terminal on my laptop.
[image]

I've browsed the internet for a solution and I'm new to coding I need help.

I went to my settings in users & groups, clicked advanced options, and changed my login shell/bin/bash instead of /bin/zsh
It helped my terminal on my Mac but it looks kinda funny, but in my Visual Studio code I get the same message saying
zsh: killed     python3
I've looked through every post and they've all said to reinstall homebrew and it hasn't fixed the issue.
Another problem im facing in VS code is when I paste
pip install PyAudio
into the terminal, it gives me
zsh: command not found: pip
It didn't do that before.